# Is it possible to collect metrics from openstack swift without Statsd?

Tags: monitoring, storage, openstack, metrics, opentsdb

I need to collect different metrics from swift servers and store those metrics into OpenTSDB.
I found that there is way to collect metrics with statsd and graphite but it isn't suitable for me because I have to store metrics into OpenTSDB.
Is there any way to store metrics from openstack swift into OpenTSDB?
I haven't found cli commands to get metrics out from Openstack swift.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this two good article explaining how to get openstack metrics including swift metrics with Prometheus. Then you can store the collected metrics into your times series database of choice (e.g. OpenTSDB)

https://blog.zhaw.ch/icclab/monitoring-an-openstack-deployment-with-prometheus-and-grafana/
https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/prometheus-openstack-exporter